# Modifying Ionic/Cordova project to use a newer gradle version

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic3

I'd like to use the Android App Bundle which available from gradle 4.9.

After the upgrade to 4.9 (I'm using Android Studio to do this operation), I can no longer build my project using the ionic cordova build command -

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Error:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.9-rc-1. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
my-gradle-path\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.9-rc-1-all.zip
```

How I can change the gradle version cordova uses to 4.9-rc-1?

I tried to change my android/gradle/gradle-wrapper but the file always reverts to the same distributionUrl after building.

In Android Studio the app bundle build works great.

Comment: Having the same issue, was able to fix it ?